# How to keep the shared secret secret when using JWT, for example?

Tags: javascript, security, jwt

There is something very basic I do not understand. In order for JWT to be secure both the client and the server must share a secret.

However, the client is typically a JavaScript application running in a browser on some remote completely unknown client machine.

Suppose I am the author of both the server and the client code, how am I supposed to ensure the safety of the shared secret on the client side?

Comment: Are you talking about the secret key used to build the JWT? Because that's not sent to the client...

Comment: This is probably one of my favorite articles (with picto) http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assume the secret is shared. It doesn't have to be. (And it only ever should be shared between systems trusting each other. You usually cannot trust the client that executes your JavaScript.)

A typical use for JWT is for the Server to produce signed data using the secret and sending the signed data (without the secret) somewhere (e.g. a client) without persisting it. When it gets the data back, it can verify (using the secret rather than a persisted copy of the data) that the data hasn't been tampered with since is has been signed.

What application does that use pattern have? You can e.g. implement token-based permissions that way and thus have authentication without identification:

Let's assume you provide a cloud storage service. A user can upload a file, to which you assign some identifier, let's say `5`. You generate a shareable URL that has the JWT-signed data "may access file #5" as one of its parameters and display that URL to the user. The user and everyone they share this link with can then access that file through that URL. You just have to verify that the signature is a valid signature created by you and that the signed data indicates the correct file. Of course, if someone with whom the user has shared the URL distributes it further, other people may get access that way, too. But without knowledge of the URL, the file isn't accessible.

Comment: So, JWT is for the server to "preserve" some limited state across the HTTP requests coming from the same user. Only the server knows the secret. Right?

Comment: Yes, though it isn't limited to HTTP requests. You could implement email address verification by signing an object containing user ID and email address, packing the result into an URL and sending that URL to the email address. When such an URL gets invoked and the signature is valid (according to your secret) then you know the email arrived and the confirmation link was clicked.

Comment: "The secret is kept on the sender and the receiver" - https://jwt.io/introduction/ Tutorial video (2:05). So i still don't understand how to keep the secret on the sender (Javascript) part.

Comment: Well, @Osi, in the use case I sketched out, both the "sender" and "receiver" would be web server, and the JS client would merely act as a proxy that can decide whether, when (and how often) to relay the message. But of course, plenty of other scenarios can be implemented with JWT, too.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as sending cookie to client on auth and then relying to it for other actions.

Yep, you can't ensure safety of client's cookies, they can be stolen. Same as jwt token can be stolen.

Good part about jwt is that token itself is not being the part of comminication as cookie, so you can use it even in `http` communications - even if somebody gets the payload or header of user's request he wont be able to create new request with other data, which is possible in case of cookies usage.

Comment: I do not get it. It is not part of the communication as a cookie, but it is part of the communication as the Bearer token in the Authorization header. The net result is the same - the server "preserves" some state across the HTTP requests from the same user. How is it different from cookies? I must be missing something here.

Comment: Well, of course jwt token is part of communication _when_ user receives it. But afterthat user sends payload and signature to the server, _not_ token itself as in case of cookies.

Comment: But in order to verify the signature the server needs the header and the payload parts of the respective JWT. Since they do not arrive on the wire, the server needs to store and fetch them from the database. If so, then it is session management. I thought JWT could eliminate the need for a session management. Again, I must be missing something.

Comment: You can use jwt for session management _OR_ for anything else. You can even write email json-encoded with jwt. Or post public post. JWT is just a standard on how to send encrypted information between two parties. Any third party, that acquires the stream - won't be able to decode it without secret key which is not part of communication. jwt is not somthing _new_ it's just a standard that describes how information should be packed (json), where sugnature and algorithm should be placed (header) and that's it. JWT is not even enventing any encryption algorythm.